# Padé approximation to the Poisson c.f.

Tags: poisson-distribution, characteristic-functions, poisson-process, pade-approximation

Poisson variable X possess characteristic function

$$  \phi_X(t) = E[e^{itX}] = e^{\lambda(z-1)} $$

where $ z = e^{it} $. If i were to obtain the Padé approximation by defining $1/e^{u} = e^{\lambda(z-1)} $ and obtaining
$$  e^{u} \approx \frac{1+1/2 u}{1-1/2 u}  $$
$$  e^{\lambda(z-1)} \approx -\frac{(2/\lambda-1)+z}{-(2/\lambda+1)+z}  $$

I should be able to inverse transform to an approximate pdf in time domain pdf, no?

But requiring poles < 1 for stable decay leads to $ 2/ \lambda +1  < 1$ which obviously is never the case. Where did I think wrong?

In this way I was thinking to obtain distribution for serial correlated Poisson process.

Comment: What do you mean by "time domain" pdf? Isn't a Poisson process usually stationary?

Pade expansions give you fake poles whenever you truncate them. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2239128/significance-of-virtual-zeroes-poles-introduced-by-the-pade-expansion-of-es for a related question I asked a while ago.

Comment: @SZN thx for your comment. Indeed the distribution of that stationary process (having variance greater than mean if correlated). Maybe higher order Padé could account for the 'double' shape of Poisson? i.e. first up than down.

Comment: Question answered, I found completely other route to what I seek. Thanks for your comment.